# VBA in ACCESS how "Flag" and "Err05" got declared ?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I do not understand where "Flag and Err05" (at the bottom of the codes)have been declared ? I have searched the entire project and can not found where the two parameters got declared.  When I try to use the below codes in another project , i got the error message "Run time error : items not found in this collection "  Any answers?

```
>Private Sub SanityCheck_Click()
>Dim St As String, WrnFlag As Boolean, j As Integer
>Dim RS As Recordset, RS1 As Recordset, i As Integer, WrongRootCauses As String
>Dim Err01 As String, Err02 As String, Err03 As String, Err04 As String
>WrnFlag = False
>If IsNull(Me.FactoryList) Then
 >   MsgBox "Select valid Factory before proceeding.", vbExclamation
>Else

>    St = "SELECT Factory, Step1, Step2, Step3, Step4, DateColumn FROM [tbl >Factory] WHERE Allowed = True and Factory = """ & Me.FactoryList.Value & """"
 >   Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(St, dbOpenSnapshot)

'-- 12NC codes check --
   > St = "SELECT Count([" & RS!Step2 & "].PLANT) AS 12NC_chk " & _
    >"FROM [" & RS!Step2 & "] " & _
   > "WHERE (((Len(Trim(IIf(Left(Trim([12NC_CODE]),3)=""000"",Right>([12NC_CODE],Len([12NC_CODE])-3),[12NC_CODE])))) Not In (0,1,12)));"
'    "WHERE (((Len(Trim([12NC_CODE]))) Not In (0,1,12)));"

   > Set RS1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(St, dbOpenSnapshot)
    >If RS1.BOF And RS1.EOF Then
     >   Err05 = "+ No 12NC issues found."
    >Else
   >     RS1.MoveFirst
    >    RS1.MoveLast
     >   If RS1![12NC_chk] = 0 Then
      >      Err05 = "+ No 12NC issues found."
       > Else
        >    Err05 = "- " & RS1![12NC_chk] & " Incorrect 12NCs found!"
         >   WrnFlag = True
       > End If
   > End If
'--

   > If WrnFlag = True Then **Flag** = vbCritical Else **Flag** = vbInformation
   > MsgBox RS!Factory & " input data sanity check:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "  " & >Err01 & vbCrLf & "  " & Err02 & vbCrLf & "  " & Err03 & _
 >       vbCrLf & "  " & Err04 & vbCrLf & "  " & Err05 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & IIf>>(WrongRootCauses = "", "", "  Unknown ADP Root Cause(s):" & vbCrLf & WrongRootCauses), Flag

   > RS.Close
    >RS1.Close
>End If
>End Sub
```

Comment: what are all these '>'

Answer (score 0):

Two posibilities

1. Unless the file have `Option explicit` in the top, you are not forced to explicitely declare variables. Which means that `Flag` and `Err05` have indeed never been declared. VBA will just create them on the fly with a `Variant` type and an initial value of `Nothing`.
2. They might be global variables declared outside of any sub in another file. Try right clicking the variable and then click *definition* in the menu, Access will show you the way.

Comment: just checked , there "Opeton explicit " on the top . why can I not find the declaration. ?

Comment: @Lauraxu I edited my answer to add another posibility

Comment: Hi, Litelite, I tried the second method . it shows "Identifier under cursor is not recognized" . But the above code just run well with any bugs. Other possibilities ?

Comment: @Lauraxu are you certain that `Option explicit` is present and not commented?

Comment: If `option explicit` is present in the file and NOT commented, then I have strictly no idea how your code is working sorry...